# Can't Add Printer with lpadmin

Tags: macos, printing

I am trying to add a Pharos printer to a Mac, running Yosemite, and the command isn't working. The problem is that the printer queue has a space in the name. The genius that set it up didn't think that would ever be a problem. The command is:

```
lpadmin -p "Pharos Printer" -E -D "Pharos Printer" -P PHAROS_PRINTER.PPD -v popup://pharos.domain.com/Pharos%20Printer
```

`%20` and quotes, or a combination of the two haven't worked yet. Anything else I can try? The above command works on printer queues that do not have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 1):

I know that in the Terminal, you can escape the space using the \ character. So, what I would write is: `Pharos\ Printer`.
That way Terminal knows that a space character is incoming.